# How this type of links works?

Tags: php, hyperlink

I've been working in php for a while and the links that I usually work on are like this :   *[ahmad.com/progress.php?id=6&method=sod](http://ahmad.com/progress.php?id=6&method=sod)*

but in some websites the links are so much different, they look like something like this : *[ahmad.com/category/main/2015/post](http://ahmad.com/category/main/2015/post)*

there is lots of" / ", I was thinking that it's may be a folder inside folder but it seems impossible, so I m wondering how this links words?

thanks

Comment: You'll want to know about `mod_rewrite` in .htaccess files.

Comment: Actually this is performed by using re-write rules. by using .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a link like https://stackoverflow.com/showQuestion.php?q_id=31252220&title=how%20this%20type%20of%20links%20word

I think
[How this type of links works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252220/how-this-type-of-links-word)
is much more descriptive and good-looking. And you can't put every new question in a folder wtih it's ID. That's why we use .htaccess files, which convert urls and tell the site what the link actually means. So if you would write something like

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^/questions/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /showQuestion.php?q_id=$1&title=$2
```

I can't tell you what everything here means, shortly, the strings inside "/"s are converted into parameters.
Here are some links (I don't have enough reputation to post them normal) where I learned .htaccess syntax, take a look at them (or anyone else, who wants to learn it or just know how it works).

www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

my.fastdomain.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect

stackoverflow.com/questions/758223/htaccess-optional-characters

stackoverflow.com/questions/24200950/htaccess-redirect-anything-after

Answer (score 0):

This is called URL re-writing. You can see a lot of frameworks use this to help parse complex URLs for APIs and stuff. Another bonus of using this system is that it makes URLs more user friendly.

From Slim's docs: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/.

And here's another tutorial: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/